# Is the definition of angular momentum $\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$ rigorous?

Tags: differential-geometry, physics

Let $\vec{r}$ be the position vector in $3\mathrm{D}$ Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $\vec{p}$ the linear momentum of point mass at $P\in\mathbb{R}^3$. The angular momentum $\vec{L}$ of that point mass with respect to the origin is defined to be
$$\vec{L} = \vec{r}\times\vec{p} = m\vec{r}\times\vec{v}.$$

This feels weird to me, as $\vec{r}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\vec{v}$ is a vector in $T_P\mathbb{R}^3$... aren't they? If so, we shouldn't be able to take their cross product, so how can this definition be fixed for the operations to make sense?

Comment: A small note: angular momentum is always measured with respect to a distinguished point $Q$. The vector $\vec r$ is then the vector $\overrightarrow{QP}$, and as such an element of tangent space $T_Q\mathbb R^3$. There's more to be said about your question, though. We have two tangent vectors now, but from different tangent spaces, which is slightly better, but probably not satisfying. Maybe someone else can fix this.

Comment: I don't know @Vercassivelaunos if we should think of $\vec{QP}$ as belonging to $T_Q\mathbb{R}^3$, tangent spaces shouldn't be able to connect to one another canonically, hence, we shouldn't be able to define a vector of the tangent space at a point as the one pointing to another point (this is what happens when you're a Spanish speaker and you try to write in English).

Comment: The vector $\vec{QP}$, @Vercassivelaunos, should still be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, as it is defined as a translation from a point of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (as an affine space) to another. I think.

Comment: On the other hand, physical space has no canonical vector space structure: it should be affine space $\mathbb A^3$, not the vector space $\mathbb R^3$. Affine spaces consist of a set of points from which $P,Q$ are taken, and a vector space $V$ of translations between those points. All tangent spaces to an affine space can be canonically identified with this vector space.

Comment: Of course, if you're working in a manifold setting, you probably want to consider more general manifolds, which might not be affine spaces. And then this kind of canonical identification breaks down...

Comment: There are two things to note here: 1) The formula assumes the manifold is Euclidean. So there is a natural isomorphism between the tangent space at each point with the Euclidean vector space. Given any two points $P, Q$, there is a vector $Q-P$ from $P$ to $Q$. Second, angular momentum is relative to a pivot point in space. This formula assumes this point is the origin $O$. $\vec{r}$ is called the position vector. For each point $P$, $\vec{r} = P - O$.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Vercassivelaunos 's comment, I think you need to rephrase your question in terms of more general manifolds.
You will then naturally build the notion of [moment map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_map).

Good luck on this long journey.

Comment: Would I, though? I went with rephrasing things with respect to $\vec{v}$ to avoid the relation between $x$ and $p$ altogether. I could've asked the same about
$$\vec{\omega} = \frac{\vec{r}\times\vec{v}}{\vec{r}^2}.$$
I will look into it anyway, it looks interesting.

Comment: It really depends how far you want the generalization to go. If for instance you replace $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n>3$, then you will need a framework for the definition of the "cross product", which will certainly involve some kind of differential form / symplectic structure. If you substitute it with a non-affine space, it will be the same again. In my opinion, you either identify $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $T_p\mathbb{R}^3$ all the time, or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{r}$ is a vector field. It has a value in the tangent space of $P$ given by,

$$ \vec{r} = x(P) \partial_x + y(P) \partial_y + z(P) \partial_z $$